# Set different offset to scrolltop when a specific link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following code that works nicely and scrolls to the top of a div when a link is clicked...

```
$(function () {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 1500);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

However what I would like to do is that when a specific set of links are clicked (#topbannerlinks a) it scrolls to the top of the div but with a different offset e.g.

```
$("#topbannerlinks a").click(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: target.offset().top -180 }, 1500);
});
```

Can I add build this function/if statement in to the above first function somehow?

I'm trying to do it this way becase I have a different height header on the target link page, and it doesnt scroll to the top correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a certain element also matches another selector by using `.is()`. For example this will return true if your link also matches `#topBanner a` and false if it's another link:

```
$(myLink).is('#topBanner a');
```

So inside your `.click()` function you can use `$(this).is('#topBanner a')` to do this check.

Instead of having the same `animate` function twice in your code, you can just set only the offset based on whether or not the link was in `#topBanner` and then always add the offset (whether it is 0 or 180)

```
if (target.length) {
    // set 180 if link is in #topBanner, otherwise 0
    var offset = $(this).is('#topBanner a') ? 180 : 0; 

    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top - offset}, 1500);
    return false;
}
```